# Is the expectation value of creation operator zero?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, second-quantization

Let $c^\dagger, c$ be creation and annihilation operators respectively. And we denote expectation value of operator $A$ calculated via Hamiltonian without interaction as $\left< A \right>_0$. In second quantization, is the equations below correct?

$ \left< c_a c_{a'} \right>_0 = 0 $

$ \left< c_a^\dagger c_{a'}^\dagger\right>_0 = 0 $

If so, why? In many materials, it seems they assume these. So I've been trying to prove them for hours, but I haven't got the solution yet.

Could anyone prove the equations? Any reference, textbook or hint will do.

---

The equations are seen, for example, in [Wikipedia - Bloch-De Dominics theorem](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%96%E3%83%AD%E3%83%83%E3%83%9B%EF%BC%9D%E3%83%89%E3%83%9F%E3%83%8B%E3%82%B7%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AE%E5%AE%9A%E7%90%86#%E7%90%86%E8%AB%96%E3%81%AE%E8%83%8C%E6%99%AF) (Japanese). This article says Bloch-De Dominics theorem is useful because you can separate multi-point correlation function into products of a factor like $ \left< c_a c_{a'} \right>_0$ and because then you can use the equations I wrote above.

Comment: What is the state $c_{a} | 0 >$? and what is the scalar product of this vector with vacuum?

Comment: I don't know the detail (as I'm a beginner) but maybe $c_a |0, \cdots, 0 (a\ th), \cdots, 0> = |0, \cdots, 1, \cdots, 0>$ where $0$ means there is no electron on the site and $1$ means there is one electron on the site. The scalar product of $c_a |0>$ is $<0| c_a^\dagger c_a|0> = <0| 0 | 0> = 0$ because $c_a^\dagger c_a$ is number operator. I'm sorry if these are not what you want me to explain...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the annihilation operator is
$$
 c_a \left| 0  \right> = 0
$$
It's conjugate part is 
$$ \left< 0  \right| c_a^{\dagger} = 0
$$
If you keep these things in mind then it is easy to see why
$$
 \left<0  \right|c_a c_a'\left | 0  \right> = 0
$$
Same thing true for the other equation also

Comment: Though this is not exactly what I wanted to know, this gave me a hint and finally I've solved my question. Thank you.